# How to include jquery in js (extjs3.3) file?

Tags: jquery, extjs3

how to include  jquery in extjs code.I want to change css class properties dynamically, using extjs and jquery

Answer (score 0):

There are no namespace conflicts between jQuery and ExtJS.  You can use both of them together.  Just include both src files.

However, you don't need jQuery to change styles dynamically.  You can use [`setStyle`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Element-method-setStyle).